# Ho to proper enqueue asset in WP?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a question and I hope you can help me. I am an amateur (quite clear :-) ) trying to enqueue some script. It works, but I have the idea that my website is loading slowly, because of an error in the implementation.

```php
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_locale_css( $uri ){
        if ( empty( $uri ) && is_rtl() && file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/rtl.css' ) )
            $uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css';
        return $uri;
    }
endif;
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' );


/**
 * Enqueue scripts.
 */
function hueman_pro_child_scripts()
{       
    wp_enqueue_script('hueman-pro-child-calculators', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/calculators.js', array(), null, true);
    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hueman_pro_child_scripts');
```

referring to

```js
/** calculators.js
 * Contains JavaScript code required by "stuff". */

// WPC7 
$("input.wpcf7-form-control, textarea.wpcf7-form-control").attr("autocomplete", "negative");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-link]").click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-link");
    return false;
  });
});

// BG COLOR NAV MOBILE  
$(".ham__navbar-toggler-two").click(function(){ 
   // changed class name
  $("#nav-mobile").toggleClass('maindisplay_white');
});

// SUBHEADER
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('.suba').addClass('scrolled');
            $('.subb').addClass('scrolled2');
        
        } else {
            $('.suba').removeClass('scrolled');
            $('.subb').removeClass('scrolled2');
            
        };
    });
});

// READMORE
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#read-more").hide();  // Hide element on default
    $(".show-readmore").click(function(){
        $("#read-more").toggle(500);
    });

    $('.show-readmore').click(function(){
      $('i').toggleClass('far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: Have you tested your idea? Do you know for a fact that this implementation is causing you load times and not something else?

Comment: Your use of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action looks correct to me. You can troubleshoot performance problems using the Chrom(ium) browser's Lighthouse function, in its devtools. Or look at the Network tab in devtools.  Honestly, with WordPress it's possible the performance problem is somewhere else than your code. WordPress performance problems are tricky to pin down.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I also thought the problem lies to wp fastes cache (for mobile), but that looks strong to me... Thanks for advice! i will check devtools, hopefully i get it